# Error importing river library in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

I successfully installed a package with `pip install river`. But in Jupyter notebook when I try to import the library, it returns the below error?

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
__init__.pxd in numpy.import_array()

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-95f3de1cb7c8> in <module>
    1 # online libraries
     ----> 2 from river import compose
    3 
     4 from river import metrics
      5 from river import preprocessing

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\river\__init__.py in <module>
    7 scikit-learn, enough so that users who are familiar with scikit-learn should feel 
right at home.
    8 """
----> 9 from . import (
     10     anomaly,
     11     base,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\river\ensemble\__init__.py in <module>
   5 
   6 """
----> 7 from .adaptive_random_forest import (
   8     AdaptiveRandomForestClassifier,
   9     AdaptiveRandomForestRegressor,

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\river\ensemble\adaptive_random_forest.py in <module>
   7 import numpy as np
   8 
 ----> 9 from river import base, metrics, stats, tree
  10 from river.drift import ADWIN
  11 from river.tree.nodes.arf_htc_nodes import (

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\river\metrics\__init__.py in <module>
   33 from .cross_entropy import CrossEntropy
   34 from .exact_match import ExactMatch
    ---> 35 from .expected_mutual_info import expected_mutual_info
   36 from .fbeta import (
      37     F1,

   ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\river\metrics\expected_mutual_info.pyx in init 
   river.metrics.expected_mutual_info()

   __init__.pxd in numpy.import_array()

   ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I don't understand why this error appears even though the library installed successfully.

Comment: seems like a dependency problem, what is the version of numpy you are using ?

Comment: the numpy version is '1.19.3'

Answer (score 2):

Instead `pip install river`
Try this:

```
pip install -U numpy
```

Comment: when I try to update numpy, libraries like tensor flow conflict with the new version